# append a div inside another and have click event on it

Tags: dynamic, click, append

I am having a parent div

```
<div id='thumb'>
```

I then have a Javascript that is running a for..loop and appends child divs inside that one depending on a number. So let's say I want 3 new divs, my loop is appending one by one giving them a class name.

At the end I have:

```
<div id='thumb'>
    <div class='newTumb1'></div>    /*this div was created in loop 1*/
    <div class='newTumb2'></div>    /*this div was created in loop 2*/
    <div class='newTumb3'></div>    /*this div was created in loop 3*/
</div>
```

my script is something like:

```
for (i=1;i<Num;i++){
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'newTumb';
    iDiv.title=count;
    var classN="newTumb"+count;
    iDiv.className = classN;
    iDiv.style.margin= '5px';
    document.getElementById('thumb').appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

The thing is that I want to be able to click on any of those new divs (newTumbx) and an event to happen. For the life of me..can't do it!!!

I know that I need to use some sort of .on(click,...) jquery event, and although I have tried a huge number of suggestions my code is just not doing it. I am not getting any error in the console, but it seems the click event is never assigned.

As I am new to all this, I would be very grateful if someone could help and tell me where I need to put the .on(click..) event and how to make the syntax

Thanks for any response and your help and time.

Comment: I see that you are not using jquery, you can add events with `iDiv.onclick = function (e) { ... };`

Comment: I have tried the .onclick but can't make it work. Could you please show me the syntax you would use and where in the code you would add it? thanks

Comment: You can also use `iDiv.addEventListener('click', function (e) { alert('clicked!'); });`

Comment: I tried both. None is working! Again no error messages or anything. Just not doing the job. I click and nothing happens.

Comment: Is there something above the divs? Maybe something with a greater z-index?

Comment: there is an img inside them. However I have tried also without them (just the div) and nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
function callback(e){
    // e is a mouse event 
    alert('Hello from: ' + e.srcElement.id);
}
for (var i=1; i < Num; i++){
    var count = i;
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'newTumb' + count;
    iDiv.title=count;
    var classN="newTumb";
    iDiv.className = classN;
    iDiv.style.margin= '5px';

    iDiv.addEventListener('click', callback);

    document.getElementById('thumb').appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

For more on mouse events look at: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Edit:
The code above had some bugs but the general idea still holds.

I made a fiddle with the solution and it added the click event. This works now. I hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/hjamal/pmn1mws5/

Comment: See if my midifications made it work the code in the fiddle is up to date.

Comment: Thanks a lot hasanain. It is getting closer. When I click into the first one it all works. It will not though if I click any of the others. In your example all of them are working. Any ideas what that might be? Also it seems although i did not change the css my styling is gone!

Comment: I think I found the problem!!! your solution was absolutely right. However my divs where positioned behind another div in the page with no background. And although I have z-index higher for my new divs it does not seem to be doing the job. Thanks very much for your time! Good pointer also by Andrea Ghidini

Answer (score 0):

you want:

```
for (i=1;i<Num;i++){
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.setAttribute('onlick', 'yourFunction()')
    iDiv.id = 'newTumb';
    iDiv.title=count;
    var classN="newTumb"+count;
    iDiv.className = classN;
    iDiv.style.margin= '5px';
    document.getElementById('thumb').appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

Comment: still does not work! where do I put the function then? Should I have it at the top?

Comment: did you put the function name in quotes? post the actual line you used to do it. If this doesn't work there is something else going on in your code that you need to fix. I don't think it matters where you declare the actual function because you're just adding a string to an html element. the browser won't look for the actual function till the onclick event occurs.

Comment: are you loading the function in a different request as you add these elements, like is this occurring after an AJAX call and the function was already loaded in the previous request? I've had an issue before where functions wouldn't bind to html elements. My solution was to move the function declaration into the ajax response handler.